# 32-bit oracle client install hangs

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, windows, client

Windows 7/x64 . installing oracle 11.2 32-bit client.  Install proceeds, then at 80% hangs on netca.  I have not had any luck finding a solution.   Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: It could be as simple as the window of the Net Configuration Assistant (netca) not coming to the front. Try alt-tab etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may have some messy registry keys hurting you.  I've filled more than a few swear jars trying to figure out Oracle Client install issues on Windows, so hopefully my pain can be your gain.  I made a couple of blog articles on the matter outlining it all.

I would suggest you [remove the existing client](https://dbaeyes.wordpress.com/2013/07/05/soup-to-nuts-oracle-11g-client-on-windows-part-2/) first which may require some manual work, then [install](https://dbaeyes.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/soup-to-nuts-oracle-11g-client-on-windows/) a new client on the cleaned system.

Hopefully that will help.